# Error deploying Streamlit app "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement StringIO"

Tags: github, deployment, io, streamlit, stringio

I'm new in the use of streamlit. I have an app and it work in the local way.
But I tried to deploy this app and it seems that the library "io" isn't recognize.
Does anyone know how to fix it ?

I've already tried several things but it doesn't works.

My repo is here :https://github.com/m-moriss/Data_challenge_RAKUTEN

I use "io" librairy in "donnees.py" and the I also put this librairy in the requirements.txt file.

[Here the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTTwN.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) is a class of the module [io](/questions/tagged/io) and not a module itself.

Also, you doesn't need to include `io` in your `requirements.txt` since it's a python's *built-in*.

```
numpy
pandas
plotly
datasets
Pillow
streamlit
streamlit-option-menu
dataset
nltk
scikit-learn
wordcloud
tensorflow
StringIO # <- remove this line
```

Comment: Thank you. I remove it and now it's running since 15 minutes. I'm going to let this and see if the deployment works

Comment: Thanks I don't have this problem anymore